# How to parse contents in zxing barcode library in android

Tags: android, zxing

I am use zxing library for scanning data matrix barcode.  I use  [zxing for barcode for scanning data matrix barcode type](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-barcode-reader--mobile-17162)  :

Barcode image :

[image: Bar code image]

Which has following detail :

LOC : VIP/ROYAL

item : 30000701293

UOI : Each

PAR : 35/50

It is working fine. I got properly output in contents.

Output :

1L+SK_CON_STR21LVIP/ROYAL.VIP/ROYAL....000000P+30000701293U+Each

So, how can i bifurgate all details ?

Answer (score 1):

You parse it by writing Java code. Whatever this text is, its format is not a general standard, and so there is no library code that is already going to parse it.

Comment: OK, How can i find that value of LOC,item,Each etc. ?

Comment: I think this is too broad a question. You should learn Java in order to understand how you write code to manipulate a string.

Comment: @SeanOwen  i m new to android and moving to implement barcode scanner can u pls tell me how can i implement barcode scanner without installation of any barcode scanner in my mobile i have tried some code but that requires to install app in my mobile using intent ?